# next_vertex function to return vertex not in_tree and has shorest distance

Tags: python

so I have this function next_vertex (which i will use as a helper functionf or prims algorithm later) which takes in two arrays, in_tree and distance and will return the vertex which is not part of the tree  (has false value in in_tree) and has the shortest value in distance array.

I have tried writing the following code but get an output of 0 instead of 3, I should be getting three because 3 is the index of the only False value in in_tree as well, and is the index of the false value's distance in the distance array but I get 0. I am not sure where I am going wrong, maybe with what I am returning?

```
 from math import inf
    def next_vertex(in_tree, distance):
        """next vertex"""
        listo = []
        for i in range(len(in_tree)):
            item = in_tree[i]
            if item == False:
                listo.append(distance[i])
        answer = min(listo)
        return distance.index(answer)
        
            
    in_tree = [True, True, True, False, True]
    distance = [inf, 0, inf, inf, inf]
    print(next_vertex(in_tree, distance))
```

#get  index of false, use that index in distance to append that to listo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not keeping the right intermediate information to achieve what you want.

Perhaps the most explicit way to achieve what you want is to expand the entries in `listo` to be pairs that include both the distance and the originating index:

```py
from math import inf
def next_vertex(in_tree, distance):
    """next vertex"""
    listo = []
    for i in range(len(in_tree)):
        item = in_tree[i]
        if item == False:
            listo.append((distance[i], i))
    answer = min(listo)
    return answer[1]

in_tree = [True, True, True, False, True]
distance = [inf, 0, inf, inf, inf]
print(next_vertex(in_tree, distance))
```

You can also form this more compactly with list comprehension:

```py
def next_vertex(in_tree, distance):
    """next vertex"""
    answer = min( ( (distance[i], i) for i, nqual in enumerate(in_tree) if not nqual) )
    return answer[1]
```